# Round about Form Copying

Tags: forms, ms-access, copy, ms-access-2016

Is there a way I can quickly mimic all the properties of a form into for a new form one without directly copying the object (Ctrl-C&V, etc)?

Edit: Looking to copy into an entirely different Access Database.

Comment: I would simply copy&paste the form, then delete all controls on it (and VBA code, if there is). <shrug>

Comment: A lot of these answers are good, but I suppose I should have mentioned that I mean to copy a form, from one access database into an entirely different one.

Comment: Then **import** the form, and then remove everything you don't need.

Comment: It should possible to do the copy between databases, You'd have to create an instance of an Access application, set it equal to the source database and then work with the objects.  If this is a one-off job, it may be faster to just import the form and then copy the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open each form in design view, set them equal to an object variable, and then set the properties of the source form equal to the proeprties of the destination form. Use a funciton like this in a public module:

```
Public Sub UpdateForm(SourceForm as string, DestinationForm as string)
    dim frm1 as new form
    dim frm2 as new form

    set frm1 = forms(SourceForm) 
    set frm2 = forms(DestinationForm}

    '* List the properties you want to copy here:

    With form2
      .RecordSource = frm1.RecordSource
      .Caption = frm1.Caption
      .DataEntry = frm1.DataEntry
      '* And so on for each property
    End With

    docmd.save acform, DestinationForm

End Sub
```

If it's not a one-off project, I'd include some code to check and open the forms if they weren't already open.

Comment: Note that complex properties, such as the forms module and controls, aren't copied over that easily

Comment: Not looking to copy controls such as Combo boxes or Buttons. But I am looking to copy things like "Default View: Continuous", Height, BG Color, and Record Source (By they a table name or a SQL statement)

Answer (score 0):

`File > Options > Object Designers > Form/Report Design View > Form template.`

Set the form template to the name of an existing form and that will be used for all new forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a form object using VBA in a slightly more simple way than what DataWriter suggests.

You can use the following statement in the immediate window:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", CurrentProject.FullName, acForm, "Form1", "Form1_Copy"
```

Where `"Form1"` is the name of the source form, and `"Form1_Copy"` is the name of the destination form.

Comment: This is the best way to copy the form itself into the new database. If he's interested in copying the form properties without importing the form, however, it will require automation.

Comment: @DataWriter you can use this to copy a form into the same database too. There's no reason it's limited to new databases. Of course, if you want to remove all form controls, that's a small extra operation. Often, copying everything and removing what you don't need is easier than copying only what you need.